# Load backend and frontend routes separately without interfering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have two kind of routes, admin routes and frontend routes.

The frontend routes

```
Route::get('{locale?}/', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@home']);
Route::get('{locale?}/{page}', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@index']);
Route::get('{locale?}/{template?}/{page}', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@detail']);
```

The backend routes

```
Route::prefix('admin/dashboard')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard'); 
});
```

Now when i type admin/dashboard or api/admin, laravel uses the frontend routes to load the views, while i want the backend views to be loaded.

So to filter out the backend routes i tried this

```
Route::group(['where' => ['page' => '^(?!admin|api)$', 'template' => '^(?!admin|api)$']], function ({
  Route::get('{locale?}/', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@home']);
  Route::get('{locale?}/{page}', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@index']);
  Route::get('{locale?}/{template?}/{page}', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\loadViewController@detail']); 
});
```

which obviously did not work

Also the frontend routes should not have something like **/website**, they should all start with **/**

My question is: How can i load the backend and frontend routes separately without interfering when called, even if they have the same url length in terms of parameters, keep in mind that the admin routes always start with /admin or /api.

Note: i can't put the backend routes before the frontend routes

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can give a look at the regular expressions constraints and try to use a `where` constraint to get all the routes that have `"admin/*"`. Hope it helps.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to you could put a constraint on the `locale` route parameter:

```
Route::pattern('locale', '^(?!(api|admin)$)(\w*)');
```

You can put this in the `boot` method of you `RouteServiceProvider` and it will now not allow the `locale` route parameter to match for `'api'` or `'admin'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can register seperate routes in RouteServiceProvider. Following is how you can do it.

Inside RouteServiceProvider.php do:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapFrontendRoutes();

    $this->mapAdminRoutes();
}
```

Definition of mapFrontendRoutes():

```
protected function mapFrontendRoutes()
{
     Route::prefix('{locales?}')
         ->middleware('frontend')
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Frontend')
         ->group(base_path('routes/frontend.php'));
}
```

Definition of mapAdminRoutes():

```
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
     Route::prefix('admin')
         ->middleware('admin')
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Admin')
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

I personally find this very useful, helps to declare interference free and logical routes. Open to feedback.

Comment: This did not work exactly, but it's nice for maintaining structure :)

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Or this is not as per the use case you are looking for? I can try to help you

Comment: It is not affecting which view is loaded. Maybe you find this repo useful https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-boilerplate/blob/master/routes/web.php

Comment: So do you want to load different ViewControllers based on the route groups, right?

Comment: Yeah i need some filter that reads out the url like ->where('page', 'home');

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to group both url's as separate groups. Example as follows :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin'], function () {
Route::post('/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
```

});

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'home', 'as' => 'home'], function () {
Route::get('/record/{id}', 'HomeController@getRecord');
```

});

Comment: Yeah, but i don't want to have routes that start with /home. Thanks for the answer though